# How to search huge JSON by using Javascript or JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, treeview

In my application, web service returns a large dataset of JSON file. This is the part of my JSON string.

```
[
       {
          "Value":"21",
          "Province":"Default",
          "Branches":[
             {
                "Value":"1108",
                "Province":"Davie",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"1107",
                "Province":"Ab area109",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"1105",
                "Province":"Hollywood",
                "IsValid":"False"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "Value":"17",
          "Province":"East",
          "Branches":[
             {
                "Value":"212",
                "Province":"area109",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"219",
                "Province":"area116",
                "IsValid":"False"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "Value":"24",
          "Province":"East11",
          "Branches":[
             {
                "Value":"211",
                "Province":"area108",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"218",
                "Province":"area109",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"1102",
                "Province":"area999",
                "IsValid":"False"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "Value":"25",
          "Province":"hilton25",
          "Branches":[
             {
                "Value":"213",
                "Province":"area110",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"220",
                "Province":"area999",
                "IsValid":"False"
             }
          ]
       }
]
```

I need to search province name and get all the nodes that match up until its parent. Which means I need to search provine name by Root level and Branche level.

as the 
**eg 1.** when the search `key = Default`, Following JSON sholud be return.

```
[
       {
          "Value":"21",
          "Province":"Default",
          "Branches":[
             {
                "Value":"1108",
                "Province":"Davie",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"1107",
                "Province":"Ab area109",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"1105",
                "Province":"Hollywood",
                "IsValid":"False"
             }
          ]
       }
]
```

**eg 2.** when the search `key = area110`, Following JSON sholud be return.

```
[
    {
      "Value":"25",
      "Province":"hilton25",
      "Branches":[
         {
            "Value":"213",
            "Province":"area110",
            "IsValid":"False"
         }
      ]
    }
]
```

How can I do this by using Javascript or JQuery. Please help me.

Comment: eg1 is clear. eg2, why area999 is included? Does that mean only parent node is the desired result, and its children should be included as-is, not filtered?

Comment: Also, is `Province` value of each item unique?

Comment: @hackape Sorry sir I don't need `area999` , I removed it.Province item not unique sir.please help me if u can

Comment: Show people what have you tried but failed.

Comment: @hackape Sir I'm new to javascript. this is my class final project. I don't have much idea to solve this.please help me

Comment: If you know how to write for loop, you know how to solve this. Tell people what you think, even the slightest idea. You simply "don't have much idea", I don't have much respect to  asking for a solution to entry level problem either.

Comment: @hackape Okay thank u sir

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, you can call `JSON.parse()` to parse that input into an array of JavaScript Objects. From there, it's pretty simple with a couple for-of loops.

```
function searchProvince(prov) {
  var result = [];
  var json; // JSON string (or you can pass it in as a function parameter)
  /*
   * if you don't already have the JSON string, get it here
   */
  var objects = JSON.parse(json); // parse JSON string as JavaScript Object array
  for (obj of objects) {
    // if the base Province matches, take the whole object
    if (obj.Province === prov) {
      result.push(obj);
    } else {
      // otherwise, only take the branches that have a matching Province
      var toAdd = {Value: obj.Value, Province: obj.Province, Branches: []};
      for (branch of obj.Branches) {
        if (branch.Province === prov) {
          toAdd.Branches.push(branch);
        }
      }
      // only add the copy if any branches were matched
      if (toAdd.Branches.length) {
        result.add(toAdd);
      }
    }
  }
  return JSON.stringify(result); // returns the result as a JSON string
  // can also return result if you want the array of JavaScript Objects
}
```

It's been a while since I've developed in JS, so if this could be cleaner, let me know!

Comment: Thank u, sir. Thank u very much. I 'll try and let u know. please keep with me

Comment: Just edited real quick to remove some quotation marks in the initialization of ```toAdd```, too used to Python objects I guess :)

Comment: Works fine,Thanks sir

Comment: @TCFB Sir, Thank for your answer. How to return JSON data if province name consists of part of the search key, as an example when the `search key = area`, that word is part of the most of the province names. How to get all of that as well

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution is to use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to keep only the `objects` that satisfies one of the next conditions:

- **A)** The `Province` property of the `object` match the related searched `key`.
- **B)** Some `object` inside the `Branches` array has a match on the searched `key`.

If the condition **B)** is satisfied, we also use `filter()` to keep only the matching `objects` inside `Branches` array.

```js
let input=[{"Value":"21","Province":"Default","Branches":[{"Value":"1108","Province":"Davie","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"1107","Province":"Ab area109","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"1105","Province":"Hollywood","IsValid":"False"}]},{"Value":"17","Province":"East","Branches":[{"Value":"212","Province":"area109","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"219","Province":"area116","IsValid":"False"}]},{"Value":"24","Province":"East11","Branches":[{"Value":"211","Province":"area108","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"218","Province":"area109","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"1102","Province":"area999","IsValid":"False"}]},{"Value":"25","Province":"N25","Branches":[{"Value":"213","Province":"area110","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"220","Province":"area999","IsValid":"False"}]}]

const filterByProvinceKey = (arr, key) =>
{
    return arr.filter(parent =>
    {
        let someChildMatch = parent.Branches.some(
            child => child.Province === key
        );

        if (parent.Province === key)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (someChildMatch)
        {
            parent.Branches = parent.Branches.filter(c => c.Province === key);
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
}

console.log("Key = 'Default':", filterByProvinceKey(input, "Default"));
console.log("Key = 'area110':", filterByProvinceKey(input, "area110"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

In the case your input is a `JSON` (string), then you will need to use [JSON.parse()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse) first

```
let input = JSON.parse(<some_json>);
```

If, instead, you don't need a strict match on the `key` and you wanted to keep register where a section of the `Province` name matched the search `key`, then you can use [String.match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) for this:

```js
let input=[{"Value":"21","Province":"Default","Branches":[{"Value":"1108","Province":"Davie","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"1107","Province":"Ab area109","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"1105","Province":"Hollywood","IsValid":"False"}]},{"Value":"17","Province":"East","Branches":[{"Value":"212","Province":"area109","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"219","Province":"area116","IsValid":"False"}]},{"Value":"24","Province":"East11","Branches":[{"Value":"211","Province":"area108","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"218","Province":"area109","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"1102","Province":"area999","IsValid":"False"}]},{"Value":"25","Province":"N25","Branches":[{"Value":"213","Province":"area110","IsValid":"False"},{"Value":"220","Province":"area999","IsValid":"False"}]}]

const filterByProvinceKey = (arr, key) =>
{
    let reKey = new RegExp(key, "i");

    return arr.filter(parent =>
    {
        let someChildMatch = parent.Branches.some(
            child => child.Province.match(reKey)
        );

        if (parent.Province.match(reKey))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else if (someChildMatch)
        {
            parent.Branches = parent.Branches.filter(c => c.Province.match(reKey));
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    });
}

console.log("Key = 'AreA':", filterByProvinceKey(input, "area"));
```

```css
.as-console {background-color:black !important; color:lime;}
.as-console-wrapper {max-height:100% !important; top:0;}
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. How to return JSON data if province name consists of part of the search key, as an example when the `search key = area`, that word is part of the most of the province names. How to get all of that as well

Comment: @Rooter You can use `String.match()` for that condition instead of the strict match using `===`. Check the last snippet on the updated answer.

Comment: Shidersz How to avoid case sensitive for search key, which means when the `searchkey = Default` JSON return properly, but when the `searchkey = default` no value returning, because there **d** is simple. Have any solution to avoid this case sensitivity

Comment: @Rooter You can create a [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) from the `key` to search using the case insensitive flag `"i"` and then use that regular expression on `match()` method. See the update on the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,hope it helps.

```js
let inp = [
       {
          "Value":"21",
          "Province":"Default",
          "Branches":[
             {
                "Value":"1108",
                "Province":"Davie",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"1107",
                "Province":"Ab area109",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"1105",
                "Province":"Hollywood",
                "IsValid":"False"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "Value":"17",
          "Province":"East",
          "Branches":[
             {
                "Value":"212",
                "Province":"area109",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"219",
                "Province":"area116",
                "IsValid":"False"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "Value":"24",
          "Province":"East11",
          "Branches":[
             {
                "Value":"211",
                "Province":"area108",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"218",
                "Province":"area109",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"1102",
                "Province":"area999",
                "IsValid":"False"
             }
          ]
       },
       {
          "Value":"25",
          "Province":"hilton25",
          "Branches":[
             {
                "Value":"213",
                "Province":"area110",
                "IsValid":"False"
             },
             {
                "Value":"220",
                "Province":"area999",
                "IsValid":"False"
             }
          ]
       }
];

var key =   prompt("Please enter the key");   // Your search key
var result =[]
for(d in inp){
if(inp[d]['Province']==key)
result.push(inp[d])
for(d1 in inp[d]['Branches'])
if(inp[d]['Branches'][d1]['Province']==key)
result.push(inp[d])

}
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Thank for your answer. I saw ur answer. I tried it.when I pass search key as `area116` its return `Province": "area109"` as well .That the problem